# How to show loader with set timeout function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, loader

I have a function that is doing some calculation, i want to add jquery loader for some time for this, i have tried the following but it is not displaying the loader not getting why?

```
 function onChangeLeaveEndDate() {
    //$('.k-loading-mask').css('display', 'block !important');
    $(".k-loading-mask").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        test();
    }, 10000);
    $('.k-loading-mask').hide();
}
```

did id do any wrong code in above? please help me how can i show a loader for specific period of time.

Comment: better use this jquery plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: @FrebinFrancis does it necessary to use a plugin to do a small thing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)  method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
try this as:

```
function onChangeLeaveEndDate() {
   //$('.k-loading-mask').css('display', 'block !important');
   $(".k-loading-mask").show();
   setTimeout(function () {
      test(); 
      $('.k-loading-mask').hide();
   }, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work out

```
function onChangeLeaveEndDate() {
            //$('.k-loading-mask').css('display', 'block !important');
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".k-loading-mask").show();
             setTimeout(function () {
                test();
            $('.k-loading-mask').hide();
             }, 10000);
            });
    }
```