# Jquery refresh & remove "hidden" attribute by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code:

```
Html

<div class="tracking-id">
     <input type="text" id="tracking_id" placeholder="Tracking id">
           <button id="tracking_button" class="btn">Tracking</button>
      </div>
<div id="tracking_frame" hidden>
    <object type="text/html" data="https://www.tracking.com/tn=" style="min-height:390px">
    </object>
/div>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
<scrip>
     $('#tracking_button').on('click', function(){
        $('#tracking_frame').removeAttr('hidden');
    });
</scrip>
```

Now i have two problems, when user enter something in the input and hit button then i need to do two things:

1. Add the input value to the url parameter "tn" at the  and make a refresh to load the data.
2. At first without data the  will be hidden so once user pressed button we need to unhide the  with new loaded data

How to achive this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already toggling the hidden attribute for your div.

Add this and check if it works:

1. Get the data attribute from object
2. Get the relevant portion of URL before `=`
3. Add your new input
4. Set the attribute in object again.

```
 $('#tracking_button').on('click', function(){
        $('#tracking_frame').removeAttr('hidden');
        let getData = $('object').attr("data"); 
        let getDataUrl = getData.split("="); 
        let newUrl = getDataUrl[0] + "=" + $('#tracking_id').val();
   $('object').attr('data',newUrl);
});
```

Comment: Amazing, can this be done after refreshing a page ? As how to show some progress ? What if some user retry with new param - it directly changes ! Instead can we do a refresh or some delay with activity indicator etc ?

Comment: Remember: if you referesh it is fresh start. Your attribute will be hidden in the first place. Then you will have to change more stuff in your code. You probably will have to save in browser storage the value entered. And use it in the next load.

Comment: You can show a loader right, for some fixed amount of time? Have a hidden loader div in your page, display it in the beginning of your function click, hide it after some time using [setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648427/how-to-show-loader-with-set-timeout-function)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but am not sure how to add activity indicator in html . If possible can you show some lights ?!

Comment: Ast I already mentioned - have a div, which is hidden at first. Shows up when you click and disappears after some time. I have added one link in the prev comment, also if you check stackoverflow you will find much better answers than I can give you right now.